# "Date and venue is" vs. "date and venue are"

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, coordinating-conjunctions

Which of the following is the correct way?

> - Date and venue **is** the top priority.
> - Date and venue **are** the top priority.

Comment: Why do you think there can be only one acceptable way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you consider date and venue to be one thing, then the first sentence is correct. Else, if the two are taken separately, then you can use *are*. However, if you use *are*, ***Date and venue are the top priorities*** would be better (rather, correct).

Answer (score 1):

The point of the sentence is, I'd say, is naming "the top priority". Therefore you'd parse it as "X *is* the top priority", where X is "Date and venue". If you're explicitly speaking about multiple entities -- "Bob and Fred are the top students" -- then "are" would be appropriate; but since "Date and venue" is being discussed as a single entity (i.e., the space-time coordinates of an event) I'd say only "is" is appropriate.